# Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution error

Tags: paypal, payment

i'm trying to use Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution.

I read https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_GB/developer/docs/pdf/hostedsolution_uk.pdf
and try with this sample form found at page 64:

```
   <form 
   action="https://securepayments.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolu
   tionApp/webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
   <input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="50">
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="HNZ3QZMCPBAAA">
   <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
   <input type="hidden" name="return" 
   value="https://yourwebsite.com/receipt_page.html">
   <input type="submit" name="METHOD" value="Pay Now">
   </form>
```

but I obtain this error:

"Errore nell'elaborazione del pagamento

Messaggio di errore"
Non è possibile elaborare questa transazione. Paga con un'altra carta."

I tried also with my sandbox business pro id, instead of the one of the sample, but I obtained always the same error!!!

Please, could you help me to understand what is wrong?

Chiara

Comment: There should not be any issue with the above code as I replace my UK sandbox account id and it worked . Did you check the value that you are passing as "business" . You need to make sure you are passing the id for the test account not for the live and the account must be pro.

Comment: I used an old business pro that I found in my sandbox account. I created another business account and with this new one all works! Thank you very much Eshan!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today and found that the sandbox business account must have the same country that is passed by the form.